# Is there any REST API available in data studio to create a report in JAVA?

Tags: java, rest, google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

I want to connect my GCP cloud sql instance with data studio and create a report using REST API.
Is there any REST API available for this?

By using data studio UI we can do that but I want to automate it using REST API.

Are their any options to automate the cloud sql instance connection and report creation other than Data Studio UI?

Answer (score 1):

You can create reports in your application ANDROID with a library... the library is 'apwlibrary'. Create the reports with that library in a pdf, [this a example for hir use](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/learn-to-generate-pdf-documents-for-your-android-application-8abd3de7fe3b)

Answer (score 0):

There is no REST API for Data Studio to create or interact with reports.

Comment: Is there any possibility that you will come up with data studio SDK or API in future.

Comment: There's always a possibility. :) But this is not on the short term roadmap.